# Lambda Calculus with State

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I want to define a typed domain-specific lambda calculus which can simulate the sequence execution like common programming language. I wonder how to give its corresponding BNF, can I use `p;F`, `let x=I in F in` and `If p then F1 else F2` to denote the sequential structure, let blinding and conditional branch?